# Negative list index?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
# node list
n = []
for i in xrange(1, numnodes + 1):
    tmp = session.newobject();
    n.append(tmp)
link(n[0], n[-1])
```

Specifically, I don't understand what the index `-1` refers to. If the index `0` refers to the first element, then what does `-1` refer to?

Comment: I think this question covers the same ground in the end as [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Negative numbers mean that you count from the right instead of the left. So, `list[-1]` refers to the last element, `list[-2]` is the second-last, and so on.

Comment: However, there is a caveat: the behavior is slightly different if you try slice notation. If you use -1 in that case, it returns one element from the last.
    >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> a[-1]
    5
    >>> a[:-1]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: @abought Isn't that normal behavior though? If I said `a[4]`, it would return 5, but `a[:4]` returns [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @abought That is solely because slice notation *excludes* the element with the index specified after the colon! `-1` still refers to the last value in the list.

Comment: Python's negative index convention makes it more hard to find off-by-one bugs.

Answer (score 18):

List indexes of -x mean the xth item from the end of the list, so `n[-1]` means the last item in the list `n`. Any good Python tutorial should have told you this.

It's an unusual convention that only a few other languages besides Python have adopted, but it is extraordinarily useful; in any other language you'll spend a lot of time writing `n[n.length-1]` to access the last item of a list.

Comment: True although not all languages are able to follow this design. In C, `n[-1]` literally means the element prior to `n[0]` and is fine if n points into an array - even if it's more normally a bug. [http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html](Slicing in D) is an interesting take on memory-safe slicing in a native language including from-right notation.

Comment: Python got this feature directly from Perl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911115/arrays-and-negative-indexes-in-perl .  To my knowledge Larry came up with it himself for Perl, but he might have gotten it from somewhere else.