# Arrays and negative indexes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am newbie in `Perl` and I am reading about arrays.
As I understand the arrays expand automatically as needed (cool!)
But I also read that we can use negative indexes to access the arrays in reverse order.
E.g. an array of 3 elements can be accessed as:
`$array[0] $array[1] $array[2]`
or
`$array[-1] $array[-2] $array[-3]`  (in reverse order).
My question is what happens for values smaller than `-3` e.g. `$array[-5]`?
Does the array expand or something?

Comment: Test it out. These types of questions are good for you to work out yourself

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: I can try it out but I am trying to understand the memory model,if that makes sense in Perl.If not I can close the question

Comment: simply: undef is what you get

Comment: You can test it out with a one liner, but be sure to use -w so all the issues are revealed. (One reason to use a scripting language is because it is so easy to test things.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read it, the result is the same as reading `$array[5]` — the value doesn't exist and you get an undef out. Going off the end to the left and going off the end to the right are the same.

If you write it, you get an error. Arrays can only auto-extend to the right.

Comment: I have a special build of Perl where my arrays face me zero-end first. They can only auto-extend away from me.

Answer (score 2):

You get an undef value if You read the value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @l = qw(A B C);
print $l[-4];
```

Output to stderr (program continues to run):

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./x.pl line 7.
```

Or:

```
my @l = qw(A B C);
print "undef" if !defined $l[-4];
```

Output:

```
undef
```

If You want to assign a value to it You get an error:

```
my @l = qw(A B C);
$l[-4] = "d";
```

Output (program exits):

```
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -4 at ./x.pl line 7.
```

And actually the interval can be modified. So an array can start any value not only 0.

```
my @l = qw(A B C);
$[ = -4; # !!! Deprecated
print $l[-4], "\n";
print $l[-3], "\n";
```

Output:

```
A
B
```

Comment: `$[` is deprecated; do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it throws the error:

Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -2