# How does negative array index in perl works?

Tags: arrays, perl

Recently I come across negative index in `perl` works. Basically when we give a negative index to a array in perl, it starts traverse from the back.
For e.g:

```
@numbers = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
print "$numbers[-1]\n";
```

It prints the output as **`6`**. If I give index as **`-2`** then it prints **`5`** and so on.
As per my understanding array memory is as below:
[image]

I wonder, how the index **`-1`** became **`n`** in perl. Can anyone please explain how does this works?

P.S: If I use negative index in `java` then it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: You can think of `$numbers[-1]` like `$numbers[ @numbers-1 ]` Also check http://stackoverflow.com/q/15911115/223226

Comment: @mpapec, Does the perl interpreter will take care of converting `-1` to `@numbers-1`?

Comment: You could say that, but minus sign just instructs perl to get elements from the end of the array.

Comment: [The answer is in your friendly Perl manual](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/pod/perldata.pod#Subscripts).

Comment: @reinierpost: Why would you possibly share a link to documentation from a version of Perl that is five years old? Surely http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Subscripts would be better?

Comment: @Dave Cross: Because most questions on Perl that I've seen, at least at this level, stem from people who turn out to be working with versions of Perl that are 10 or even 15 years old.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain how does this works?

The Perl API call to fetch an array element, `av_fetch`, does the C equivalent of

```
my $real_index = $index < 0 ? @array+$index : $index;
```

Or [more precicely](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/78add018a01221839c23f0cfecc3110bb28d038f:/av.c#l263),

```
$index += $#array+1 if $index < 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

## [More About Indices](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=739305)

We said earlier that array indices are non-negative integers. While this is strictly true at some level, perl conveniently lets you index elements from the end of the array using negative indices. `-1` refers to the last element, `-2` to the next-to-last element, and so on. To oversimplify a bit, `-1` acts like an alias for `$#array`... but only in the context of indexing `@array`!

**So the following are equivalent:**

```
$array[ -1 ]
$array[ $#array ]
```

**But beware:**

```
@array[ 0 .. $#array ]
```

can not be written as:

```
@array[ 0 .. -1 ]
```

because in this situation the -1 is an argument of the .. range operator, which has no idea what "highest index number" is actually wanted.

---

It works because it's really just an alias when used in the context of an index for an array.

Answer (score 3):

Perl arrays are not C arrays. They are more like Java's `javal.util.ArrayList`. This data structure includes some metadata like the length of the array, not just the start pointer.

Now in Perl, when the array accessing code sees a negative index, it adds the length of the array: Given an array of length `n+1`, then `-1 + (n+1)` is index `n`. This is a convenient language feature to have, but some languages (especially “system programming languages” like C) want to avoid the implied overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented feature. (See the **Subscripts** section of `perldoc perldata`.)

Answer (score 0):

While this is strictly true at some level, perl conveniently lets you index elements from the end of the array using negative indices. -1 refers to the last element, -2 to the next-to-last element, and so on. To oversimplify a bit, -1 acts as an alias for `$#array`... but only in the context of indexing `@array`!