# Converting Python to C++ - index in lambda

Tags: python, c++

I am new to python, and I am trying to convert some python code to C++.

path is a string, WORDS is a list of strings.

python snippit:

```
suggestions = filter(lambda x: x[0] == path[0] and x[-1] == path[-1], WORDS)
```

Because I do not know python at all, I have **trouble understanding the notion of 0 and -1.** Do they represent indexes of these arrays, like `i` and `i-1` would in C++?

Here is my attempt to convert:

```
  vector<string>suggestions; 
int len = path.length();

  for (string &x : dictionary) //for each word in some dictionary
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
          if (path[i] == x[i] && path[i-1] ==x[i-1])
            suggestions.push_back(x);
            break;
        }
```

Even though I think it should be right, this code isn't doing what I want it  to do. The filtered list from the python code is much shorter than the vector from the C++ code.

Comment: The lambda function is filtering for the words that begin and end with the same letter as `path`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is a sequence in python, so the indicies you're asking about are referring to specific characters. Index 0 means the same thing in Python as C++. Negative indexes in python count backwards from the end of the sequence, so Index -1 is the last character in the string.

```
vector<string> suggestions; 
int len = path.length();

for (string &x : dictionary) //for each word in some dictionary
  if(path[0] == x.front() && path[len-1] == x.back())
    suggestions.push_back(x);
```

The lambda creates a function that takes a string and checks the first and last characters. That function is then passed into `filter`, which calls it on each element of `WORDS`. `filter` returns an iterable of all the words for which the lambda returned true.

Comment: yes, len-1. beat me to it! Thank you! I was doing x[x.length() - 1] instead of x.back(), although your solution looks much cleaner

Comment: Fixed, thank you. You might also be able to use `front` and `back` on path, depending on the type of `path`. That would make your code even cleaner, and you wouldn't need a variable for length.

Answer (score 2):

> I have trouble understanding the notion of 0 and -1.

See [[Negative index to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-index-to-python-list)] and [[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)].

> Negative numbers mean that you count from the right instead of the left. So, list[-1] refers to the last element, list[-2] is the second-last, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Index 0 is the first element, and index -1 is the last element. If `foo` contains `[4, 6, 8]`, `foo[0]` would be `4` and `foo[-1]` would be `8`.

In the case of a string, they are the first and last character respectively. So, `string::front()` and `string::back()` in C++11, otherwise access with 0 and length-1 as normal.