# updating a deep key in a Nested JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
    "email": "abctest@xxx.com", 
    "firstName": "name01", 
    "surname": "Optional"
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2"
        }, 
        "layer03": [
            {
                "inner_key01": "inner value01"
            }, 
            {
                "inner_key02": "inner_value02"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "surname": "Required only$uid"
}
```

am expecting a update request as:

```
{
                "email": "XYZTEST@gmail.com",
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "layer01.key3": "newvalue03",
                "layer01.layer02.key1": "newvalue01"
            },
```

the deeper keys are separated using `"."`

am using python2.7. Can anyone advice me on this.. am really stuck at this!!

this is what i was working with:

```
def updateTemplate(self,templatename, data):
    template= self.getTemplatedata(templatename) # gets the python object with the data from original file

    for ref in data:
        k= ref
        keys= ref.split(".")
        temp= template
        if len(keys)>1:
            temp= template[keys[0]]
            for i in range(1,lens(keys)-1):
                print keys[i]
                if type(temp) is dict:
                    temp =temp[keys[i]]



            temp[keys[len(keys)-1]]= data[k]
            print temp

            template.update(temp)        
        else:
            template[k]= data[k]   
    print template
```

update added a whole new key in the template object. I need to update the key in last temp to template object

the template object displayed this:

```
{   u'email': u'abctest@xxx.com',
    u'firstName': u'Valid AU$uid',
    u'key1': u'value1',
    u'key2': u'value2',
    u'key3': u'value03',
    u'key4': u'value4',
    u'layer01': {   u'key1': u'value1',
                    u'key2': u'value2',
                    u'key3': u'value03',
                    u'key4': u'value4',
                    u'layer02': {   u'key1': u'value01', u'key2': u'value2'},
                    u'layer03': [   {   u'inner_key01': u'inner value01'},
                                    {   u'inner_key02': u'inner_value02'}]},
    u'layer02': {   u'key1': u'value01', u'key2': u'value2'},
    u'layer03': [   {   u'inner_key01': u'inner value01'},
                    {   u'inner_key02': u'inner_value02'}],
    u'surname': u'Required only$uid'}
```

Comment: Show your attempts please.

Comment: i have edited the question with my code appended at the end,.. please look into it

Comment: It seems to work for me. What's not working for you? You say "update added a whole new key in the template object" but this isn't possible with Python dictionaries: keys are unique.

Comment: i have posted the output also now.... its adding new nested keys to my object

Comment: @JulienBernu Can u help me with this?... because.. at the end of the iteration what i have is temp  with the deepest dictionary details only.. if i pass that to the template object in update, it will add it is unique in the top layer..

Comment: @CameronLee please have a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is really close but there's a few things in it that complicate things unnecessarily. This makes it easy to miss the key line that's causing the problem:

```
template.update(temp)
```

temp is the child-most dictionary of the template but here you set the original template to have all it's children too. Comment this line out and it should work.

Some of the things that I cleaned up to make this line easier to find:

- Don't hardcode the case where there's only one element in the `keys` list. The loop can handle it.
- In Python, there's a nice shorthand for `keys[len(keys)-1]`: `keys[-1]`. See [Negative index to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-index-to-python-list)
- Instead of using enumerate and checking if the type of temp is a dict, simply don't loop over the last key (this could change the behaviour a bit for other input)
- Using pprint. It pretty prints things like lists and dictionaries.

Put together, a simplified version looks like this:

```
import pprint

def updateTemplate(self, templatename, data):
    template = self.getTemplatedata(templatename) # gets the python object with the data from original file

    for ref in data:
        keys = ref.split(".")
        temp = template
        for key_part in keys[:-1]:
            temp = temp[key_part]
        temp[keys[-1]] = data[ref] # Because dictionaries are mutable, this updates template too

    pprint.pprint(template)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was able to solve this using Pydash. very simple with that.!!

Answer (score 0):

As much as I'd like to help you out, I find your code confusing, but I'll do my best. Here it goes

For starters, by `temp= template` do you mean to do `temp= copy.deepcopy(template)`? Remember to `import copy` [Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

I get that template is a dictionary, but what do you want to achieve by referencing `template` to `temp`, tweaking `temp` then **adding**

> `template.update(temp)`

`temp` to `template` which in fact `temp` is a reference to `template`?

How about we scrap the code and start off fresh.

i.e. Input is

```
{
    "email": "XYZTEST@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "layer01.key3": "newvalue03",
    "layer01.layer02.key1": "newvalue01"
}
```

Existing data is:

```
{
    "email": "abctest@xxx.com", 
    "firstName": "name01", 
    "surname": "Optional"
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2"
        }, 
        "layer03": [
            {
                "inner_key01": "inner value01"
            }, 
            {
                "inner_key02": "inner_value02"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "surname": "Required only$uid"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "email": "XYZTEST@gmail.com", 
    "firstName": "firstName", 
    "surname": "Optional"
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "newvalue03", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "newvalue01", 
            "key2": "value2"
        }, 
        "layer03": [
            {
                "inner_key01": "inner value01"
            }, 
            {
                "inner_key02": "inner_value02"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "surname": "Required only$uid"
}
```

Kindly confirm if this is the result your expecting, so I can help you with your brainstorming.

Comment: This is exactly what i was expecting.

Comment: was doing some R&D on working with Dictionaries using python. Came across 'pydash'. it actually solved my problem. With it i can access the deep nodes directly by "." eg: layer01.layer02.key......