# tf.slice and tf.strided_slice

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

trying to comprehend tensorflow strided_slice and slice

```
x = tf.constant(np.array(   [[[111, 112, 113], [121, 122, 123]],
                            [[211, 212, 213], [221, 222, 223]],
                            [[311, 312, 313], [321, 322, 323]]]))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("tf.shape ------------------")
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(x)))
    print("tf.slice ------------------------")
    print(sess.run((tf.slice(x, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3]) )))
    print("tf.strided_slice ------------------------")
    print(sess.run(tf.strided_slice(x, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1])))
    print(sess.run(tf.strided_slice(x, [1, -1, 0], [2, -3, 3], [1, -1, 1])))
    print(sess.run(x[1,-1,0]))
    print(sess.run(x[2,-3,3]))
```

output

```
tf.shape ------------------
[3 2 3]
tf.slice ------------------------
[[[211 212 213]]

 [[311 312 313]]]
tf.strided_slice ------------------------
[[[211 212 213]]]
[[[221 222 223]
  [211 212 213]]]
221
ValueError: slice index -1 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for 'strided_slice_8' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [3,2,3], [3], [3], [3] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <2 -3 3>, input[2] = <3 -2 4>, input[3] = <1 1 1>.
```

for tf.slice i understand we have to mentions slice sizes in each dimension and hence out of range values makes sense. but in strided slice the end is a tensor index in the tensor itself, how come  out of size value is valid.

Example is taken from
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice

Trying to implement folding layer part from paper [A Convolutional Neural Network for Modelling Sentences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2188)

> In the formulation of the network so far, feature detectors applied to
>   an individual row of the sentence matrix s can have many orders and
>   create complex dependencies across the same rows in multiple feature
>   maps. Feature detectors in different rows, however, are independent of
>   each other until the top fully connected layer. Full dependence
>   between different rows could be achieved by making M in Eq. 5 a full
>   matrix instead of a sparse matrix of diagonals. Here we explore a
>   simpler method called folding that does not introduce any additional
>   parameters. After a convolutional layer and before (dynamic) k-max
>   pooling, **one just sums every two rows in a feature map component-wise**.
>   For a map of d rows, folding returns a map of d/2 rows, thus halving
>   the size of the representation. With a folding layer, a feature
>   detector of the i-th order depends now on two rows of feature values
>   in the lower maps of order i − 1. This ends the description of the
>   DCNN.

Comment: used tf.split and tf.reduce_sum to achieve the sum of 2 rows, still my question about tf.strided_slice is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The ValueError produced doesn't have anything to do with the first 2 calls to Strided_Slice. Your use of the Strided_Slice operation is correct in

> print(sess.run(tf.strided_slice(x, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1])))
>
> print(sess.run(tf.strided_slice(x, [1, -1, 0], [2, -3, 3], [1, -1, 1])))

Your issue is with the call to

> print(sess.run(x[2,-3,3]))

A negative index in a python array iterates in reverse through the array.

For example, given an array like this

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

A call to arr[-1] would yield 'f'. Similarly, a call to arr[-4] would yield 'c'. What would happen if we tried calling arr[-7]? This would be trying to access the index -1, which would throw an error.

Keep in mind that arrays in Python have 0-based indexing. Your call to x[**2**,-3, 3] initially accesses the element at index 2 (3rd element) in the outer array, which is

```
[[311, 312, 313], [321, 322, 323]]
```

Now, in this outer array, there are 2 elements. However, your call x[2, **-3**, 3] attempts to access the element at index -1 as it iterates from the end of the array. This is what yields the error

> slice index -1 of dimension 1 out of bounds

**NOTE**: The last index you try to access in x[2, -3, **3**] will also yield a ValueError because it is attempting to access an index not in the array. To fix this, your call could be x[2, -2, 2].

Here are a few links about Strided Slicing, Slicing, and array indexing in Python:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

[Negative list index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index/11367936)