# -1 in the index of a list in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I recently came across the below piece of code in our application

```
var updateDefinition = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<OverviewProfile>()
            .Set(a => a.Advisors[-1].IsCurrent, advisor.IsCurrent);
```

In the above code, `Advisors` is a `List` and [`UpdateDefinitionBuilder`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionBuilder_1_Set__1_1.htm) is from MongoDB driver.

Could you please let me know the use of **-1** in the index of the list?

***Editing after the below comments/answers***

The `OverviewProfile` class is as below:

```
public class OverviewProfile: BaseInvestorProfile
{
    //Other properties

    public List<Advisor.View.Advisor> Advisors { get; set; }
    public OverviewProfile(int id): base(id)
    {
        Advisors = new List<Advisor.View.Advisor>();
    }
}
```

And this is this the working code. This code updates the data to the mongo db based on the condition. There are no other methods inside this class, just other properties.

This is one class, but the same usage is there for properties of multiple class, and even when we add a new `List` property and check, it works fine.

Comment: This shouldn´t work at all. Usually an index of -1 is returned by methods like `InfexOf`, to return the first occurence of a particular instance. -1 usually means this item wasn´t found. Apart from this an index of -1 passed to a `List<T>` will cause an `ArgumentException`, as the index must not be smaller zero.

Comment: Is it possible that the implementer or Advisors has overridden the square bracket indexer?  I'd be *guessing* that they're using is to apply the value to all elements in the list.  But that's really nasty

Comment: I would assume that `.Advisors` is *not* an instance of the .NET `List<T>`. Its a special implementation that has overloaded the `[index]` operator, like LordWilmore said, and that `-1` addresses the last entry in the list.

Comment: What does `a.Advisors[-1]` return, when you debug it. I can hardly imagine it even *does*.

Comment: I think Evk is right, more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index

Comment: Is this `List` really `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`?

Comment: I´m starting to think we should close that question as unclear, as from the currently posted code it´s impossible to run that code without an exception. There must be something hidden, that we can only guess about as long as we have no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP updated the post with the code. It is broken indeed.

Comment: This is a list @MuhammadAhmad, am not able to debug that line, it just skips past it

Comment: @PatrickHofman I allready saw, but from that it´s impossible to run successfully.

Comment: Indeed, unless that code never got executed... @HimBromBeere

Comment: @gvk did you step *into* (F11)  with your debugger when you´re at the `Set`-line?

Comment: Am not getting any exception or there are no other implementations/overload for this. @HimBromBeere, yes with F11

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using overload of `UpdateDefinitionBuilder<T>.Set` which expects `Expression`. This expression is not compiled and executed directly but instead is converted to native mongodb syntax and is used as part of mongo db query (same as how Entity Framework or other ORM converts expressions to SQL). This basically says "update all overview profiles and set IsCurrent flag of first advisor that matches criteria to `advisor.IsCurrent` value". Because mongodb allows negative indexes (meaning - relative to the end of collection) - C# mongodb driver can convert your expression to valid mongodb query (but see update below).

Update. As stated [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531), -1 still has *special* meaning for mongodb C# driver. It will be converted to [positional update operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_):

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document

For example:

```
var updateDefinition = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<OverviewProfile>()
    .Set(a => a.Advisors[-1].IsCurrent, false);

colleciton.UpdateOne(c => c.Advisors.Any(r => r.IsCurrent), updateDefinition);
```

Will be converted to something like:

```
"updates": [{
        "q": {
            "Advisors": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "IsCurrent": true
                }
            }
        },
        "u": {
            "$set": {
                "Advisors.$.IsCurrent": false // <- your expression
            }
        }
    }
]
```

However, point about negative index meaning relative to the end of colleciton in mongodb still holds, because any other negative index except -1 (for example, -2), will be converted to query like this:

```
{ "$set" : { "Advisors.-2.IsCurrent" : false} }
```

Comment: What would be the mongo-expression created from the statement?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've updated answer with more information about this.

Comment: Using `-1` to indicate the positional operator no longer works as of the 2.19.0 driver since (LINQ3 has been made the default LINQ provider, and LINQ3 [doesn't support this syntax](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4079)).

Answer (score 1):

If `a.Advisors` is a `List<T>` indeed, there is no use. That will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

What is more likely, that this is some custom class or implementation over `List<T>` where the `-1` value passed onto the indexer means something like the 'default' value.

Whatever it is, I think it is a bad design and should be avoided.

Comment: Just to add an official reference... Look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0c65bec4d3fac21e.html)

Comment: "implementation over `List<T>`"? The indexer of a list isn´t virtual, you can´t override it (you can hide it however).

Comment: The *class* can have a custom implementation, the indexer indeed can be hided using `new`. @HimBromBeere

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I can't believe I'd not thought of that unchecked (uint) trick. I'm not sure if it's horrifying or just mildly amusing to see it in the BCL.