# How the index in list works when index is -1

Tags: python, indexing

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = list1.insert(-1, 100)
list2 = [1,2,3,4,100,5]
```

I can't understand why the result becomes like above...

Comment: `insert()` function insert value at `len(list) - position`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative list index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index)

Comment: Can You try with different negative values? -2, -3, -4, -5 ? Check the result and You will get the answer. Good luck.

Comment: @zolv Trial-and-error is not the best way to learn programming. Read the documentation is better.

Answer (score 2):

the minus index counts from the right. So you're insert is inserting before the last item on the list. To add an item to the end of the list use:

```
list1.append(100)
```