# What is the difference between [-2:] and [2:]?

Tags: python, arrays

**Question**
Given a string, return a new string made of 3 copies of the last 2 chars of the original string. The string length will be at least 2.

This is what I did, but it didn't return true on every case.

```
def extra_end(str):
    return str[2:]*3
```

So I checked the solution and found this answer:

```
def extra_end(str):
    return str[-2:]*3
```

My question is what's the difference between `[-2:]` and `[2:]` ?

Comment: They are drastically different. Have you tried to see what your implementation does?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index.  It's for lists, but this also applies to strings.

Comment: Off-topic, but since `str` is the python type for strings, you'd be better off naming your parameter differently (original_string maybe).