# How would you explain the following: [position*-1] in Python? The * is throwing me off

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m practicing reading and writing explanations of Python code so I better understand what in the world I’m reading. I came across the below:

```
orderLog = [ ]
N = 5
def get_last(position):

    if position <= N and position <= len(orderLog):
     return orderLog[position * -1]
```

There is more code following but I need some assistance understanding the last line starting with return. Am I multiplying the parameter ‘position’ by -1 and if so.. why?    Also, further down I see:

```
Choice = -1
```

Again this -1 is puzzling me.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. I hope that `OrderLog` vs `orderLog` isn't a typo. To get you thinking, what happens if we access a list with a negative index (e.g. `some_list[-1]`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative list index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index)

Comment: A negative list index means you're counting _backwards_ from the _end_ of the list, instead of _forward_ from the _beginning_.  i.e. `mylist[-2]` means "The second-to-last item in the list`.

Comment: @TrebledJ   It was a typo! I fixed it thank you. As for your questions:  I think you count the element in the list from the right. So why is there a   *   symbol? Am I multiplying the first element from the right with the parameter 'position'?

Comment: @JohnGordon  What is the purpose of the  *  symbol in this case than?

Comment: it multiplies `position` with `-1`,

Comment: @LunaLoveDove That would be `orderLog[-1] * position`. Since you're doing `orderLog[position * (-1)]`, you're instead indexing `orderLog` by a _negative_ `position`. This is equivalent to `idx = position * -1; return orderLog[idx]` (or indeed, and more readably: `return orderLog[-position]`)

Comment: It helps if you play around with the function. (E.g. try doing `orderLog = [10, 20, 30]` and calling `get_last(1)`, `get_last(2)`, `get_last(3)`. Further, what happens if you try `get_last(0)`, `get_last(4)`?) Exploration. :)

Comment: BTW, the `position * -1` spelling is unusual. Not wrong, but most people would spell that simply as `-position`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative list indexes count from the back. Consider this hypothetical list:

```py
# positive indexes
#  0    1    2    3    4    5    6
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# -7   -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1
# negative indexes
```

Multiplying by negative one simply inverts the sign of your value. I'll assume that `position` is usually positive, so this code reads:

> If `position` is less than or equal to `N`, and position is less than or equal to the length of `orderLog`, then return the element that is `position` spaces from the end.