# Printing the extension of a file name in python

Tags: python-3.x, repr

Can Anyone explain why we are taking [-1] and the use of repr function over here. 
Can't we use any other function ?

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
f_extns = filename.split(".")
print ("The extension of the file is : " + repr(f_extns[-1]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding repr( ) function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python)

Comment: Note#1: `split()` returns a list of substrings; `f_extns[-1]` just gives you the last element of that list. Note#2: using `repr()` in the print call gives you e.g. a nice `The extension of the file is : 'txt'` for a txt file; without the `repr()`, that would just be `The extension of the file is : txt`.

Comment: Note#3: actually, I think it could be more readable to use a simple f-string here, e.g. `print(f"The extension of the file is '{f_extns[-1]}'")`

Comment: @palak soni can you please check if your query has been answered. If yes, then please accept this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, that you have shared :

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
f_extns = filename.split(".")
print ("The extension of the file is : " + repr(f_extns[-1]))
```

Use of `repr()` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python).

`split()` method will split the string on the occurrence of `.` and you will be getting an list type of object as a result.
You can check that by `type(f_extns)` which is `<class 'list'>`.

As extensions are after **dot** for retrieving last element of the list by using [negative index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index) `f_extns[-1]` or you can use `f_extns[len(f_extns) - 1]`.

Another way you can achieve this by :

```
import os
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")  # demo.py
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)    # name = "demo", ext = ".py"
ext_with_dot = ext[1:]
print ("The extension of the file is : " + ext)
```