# returing a list of diagonals in square matrices (simplification)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to return the diagonals i.e. from left to right and from right to left in a given matrix, Im using list comprehensionsto do so but I came up, in my eyes with a to complicated comprehension that returns the left to right matrix.

I was wondering if there are simpler ways to write a comprehension that returns the right to left diagonal ? Also, given that im a noob, im only beginning to dive into learning the language, i was wondering if the right_left comprehension is even conventional ?

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]
left_right = [arr[i][i] 
              for i in range(len(arr))]
right_left = [arr[i][[-j 
              for j in range(-len(arr)+1,1)][i]] 
              for i in range(-len(arr),0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
left_right = [arr[i][-(i+1)] for i in range(len(arr))]
```

For explanation of negiative indicies read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367936/8326775

Comment: i like this one its really simple

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off learning about [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html), which has a function for [diagonals](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) built-in

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],
                       [4,5,6],
                       [7,8,9]])
>>> np.diag(matrix)
array([1, 5, 9])
>>> np.diag(matrix, k=1)
array([2, 6])
>>> np.diag(matrix, k=-1)
array([4, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [list(reversed(matrix[i]))[i] for i in range(len(matrix))]

 # more transparent version:

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    row = list(reversed(matrix[i]))
    el = row[i]
    print("reversed row {} = {} -> extract element {} -> gives {}".format(i, row, i, el))

#reversed row 0 = [3, 2, 1] -> extract element 0 -> gives 3
#reversed row 1 = [6, 5, 4] -> extract element 1 -> gives 5
#reversed row 2 = [9, 8, 7] -> extract element 2 -> gives 7
```