# State vector representation in Python

Tags: python, vector

In a Python code if x is state vector, what is the meaning of  `z = -x[-2][0] / x[-1][0]`. Basically, what will be taken as `-x[-2][0]`?

I need to understand this part from a sample code:

```
for frequency in frequencies:
    A = 1.0j * 2 * np.pi * frequency * self.timescale * self.M - self.J
    lu = splu(A)
    x = lu.solve(self.b)
    # The model is set up such that the voltage is the penultimate
    # entry and the current density variable is the final entry
    z = -x[-2][0] / x[-1][0]
```

Comment: What are the imports for this file? In particular, what is `splu()` ?

Comment: What library are you using to implement the state vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative list index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index)

Comment: From the comments above it … it’s the impedance!

Comment: The z is the impendance and the states are voltage and current. My quention is in -x[-2][0] , what is the meaning of using [0]. I know [-2] will represent second last element whereas [-1] refer the last element.